# Wrong file names and lines in stack trace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I moved a web application from CRA to Webpack + Babel and came across the problem.

If I imitate an error, CRA App and Webpack App will have the same first part of the error in the browser console.

[image]

But there is a big difference in the second part.

In app with CRA it look like that: [image]

But there is a mess with names and lines in app with Webpack :
[image]

In my webpack.config I already have:

```
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'
```

How can I fix webpack error stack trace which has wrong names+lines and get something similar to CRA?

Comment: You don't appear to have asked an actual question!

Comment: @phuzi if I have wrong names and lines it's obvious that I want to get the correct ones. Isn't?  Anyway I've edited the question.